# How to pull counts in a SELECT statement in a iterative manner against values of a column from another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

**Table structure (oracle):-**

- BOOK_MASTER table has the most essential data like BOOK_TYPE (Fiction/Non-Fiction), BOOK_STATUS (available/unavailable) and BOOK_ID (unique for each book).
- BOOK_COUNTRY_INFORMATION table contains COUNTRY_CODE and BOOK_ID columns. COUNTRY_CODE has 209 distinct values.
- BOOK_XREF table contains BOOK_IDENTIFIER, BOOK_IDENTIFIER_TYPE and BOOK_ID columns.

**Aim:-**
To pull the number of SKU codes`(BOOK_IDENTIFIER_TYPE=2)` that are Non-fiction`(BOOK_TYPE=2)` for each country`(BOOK_COUNTRY_INFORMATION.COUNTRY_CODE)`. 
I can't possibly (or want to) write an individual SQL statement for each of those 209 countries to cover counts of SKU codes for all countries.

**Question:-** 
How do I write SELECT statement in a iterative manner against values of a `(BOOK_COUNTRY_INFORMATION.COUNTRY_CODE)` column to get an output something like

```
SKU_CODE_COUNT | COUNTRY_CODE
       4350234 | US
         50456 | SG
            45 | (null)
         50890 | TR
        350346 | TW
        350032 | CA
        350453 | SI
         50287 | MN
          0368 | SD
            47 | SR
               | etc.
```

**Attempt:-**
I know the basic SQL to get the counts (as pasted below) and tried adding the column of country code to it (adding which this fails to run). I know this probably requires some kind of function to achieve what I'm trying to do and I tried researching about it on google but I'm still stuck on this. I'm a beginner in SQL and I appreciate any insight/help on this!

```
SELECT COUNT(XR.BOOK_IDENTIFIER) AS SKU_CODE_COUNT, CI.COUNTRY_CODE
FROM BOOK_MASTER BM
INNER JOIN BOOK_COUNTRY_INFORMATION CI ON CI.BOOK_ID=BM.BOOK_ID
INNER JOIN BOOK_XREF XR ON XR.BOOK_ID=BM.BOOK_ID
WHERE BM.BOOK_STATUS='1' AND BM.BOOK_TYPE='2' AND XR.IDENTIFIER_TYPE='2';
```

Comment: Please post sample input data..

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT CI.COUNTRY_CODE, COUNT(XR.BOOK_IDENTIFIER) AS SKU_CODE_COUNT
FROM BOOK_COUNTRY_INFORMATION CI
LEFT JOIN BOOK_MASTER BM
   ON CI.BOOK_ID=BM.BOOK_ID
  AND BM.BOOK_STATUS='1' 
  AND BM.BOOK_TYPE='2' 
LEFT JOIN BOOK_XREF XR 
   ON XR.BOOK_ID=BM.BOOK_ID
  AND XR.IDENTIFIER_TYPE='2'
GROUP BY CI.COUNTRY_CODE;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. That works. Although I'm scratching my head to understand why. Adding the conditions to the join clause -does that make the huge difference here (if yes, why?) or the group by clause? Thanks. I will choose as answer once you reply.

Comment: @Fenil The point is to use `LEFT JOIN` to get all countries and COUNT(col) does not count NULLs so you will get 0 when no book is found